# Trying to change HSV color of a pixel, and getting unexpected color as a result. Why?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, hsv, android

The first of the following two images, `rgbaMat.bmp`, is a `5px*5px` `.bmp` image in `RGBA` format. This image was read from sdcard using `Highgui.imread` and then converted to `HSV` using `Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);` resulting in `hsvMat.bmp` (the second image):

[image]  [image]

The following are the same images enlarged to `100px*100px` in MS Paint, for viewing purposes.

[image] [image]

Then after executing the following code, the image I got `changedMat.bmp` is given as follows, followed by its enlarged version.

[image]

[image]

**The problem is that what I expected when writing the code was that the alternate pixels should have *white* (`H=0, S=0, V=255`) and *black* (``) hues respectively, as can be checked [in the HSV section on this website](http://colorizer.org/). But what I am getting is red and black.**

**The question is why? Where am I going wrong?**

```
public void doProcessing(View view) {
    Mat rgbaMat = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/rgbaMat.bmp");

    Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/hsvMat.bmp", hsvMat);//check

    int counter=1;
    for (int firstCoordinate = 0; firstCoordinate<hsvMat.rows(); firstCoordinate++) {
        for (int secondCoordinate = 0; secondCoordinate<hsvMat.cols(); secondCoordinate++) {
            Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY " + Arrays.toString(hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)));//check

            double[] pixelChannels = hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate);

            if (counter%2 != 0) {
                pixelChannels[0]=0;
                pixelChannels[1]=0;
                pixelChannels[2]=255;
            } else {
                pixelChannels[0]=0;
                pixelChannels[1]=0;
                pixelChannels[2]=0;
            }

            hsvMat.put(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate, pixelChannels);

            counter++;
            Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY PAPPY" + Arrays.toString(hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)));//check
        }
    }
    Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/matChanged.bmp", hsvMat);//check
}
```

...................................................................................................................................................................

---

***EDIT:***

The `Log.i` statements on Line#11 and Line#28 print out the following output, **which is good**.

```
01-12 13:46:44.445: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.445: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.445: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.445: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.445: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.446: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.447: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.447: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.447: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.447: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.447: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.448: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.449: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.449: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.449: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.450: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.451: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [29.0, 252.0, 255.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY [0.0, 0.0, 164.0]
01-12 13:46:44.452: I/MainActivity(29690): HAPPY PAPPY[0.0, 0.0, 255.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to check, I converted the HSV for the pixel into [Android Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) and logged the value of Android Color using

```
//CONVERTING HSV COLOR TO ANDROID COLOR
//Step 1: Convert double[] to float[]. Step 2: Scale the float[]. STep 3: Use Android's HSVToColor method
float[] channelsFloatArrayScaled = new float[3];
for (int i = 0; i < hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate).length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        channelsFloatArrayScaled[i] = ((float) hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[i]) * 2;// TODO Wrap an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException wrapper
    } else if (i == 1 || i == 2) {
        channelsFloatArrayScaled[i] = ((float) hsvMat.get(firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate)[i]) / 255;// TODO Wrap an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException wrapper
    }
}
int androidColor = Color.HSVToColor(channelsFloatArrayScaled);
Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY PAPPY FAPPY" + androidColor);//check
```

The result was `-1` and `-1777216` in alternate pixels, which stand for white and black.

So all is good in the hood, except that I don't know what OpenCV is doing while writing the image to sdcard (the last `imwrite`).